# I was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am making card game with batch-file but I get **I was unexpected at this time**  so what i can do without changing variables.

```
set n1=IJ I
set m1=I HI
set n2=IJ I
set m2=I DI
if %n1%==%n2% (
    if %n1%==IJ I set WL=win
)else (
set WL=lose
)
echo +--+ +--+
echo %n1% %n2%
echo %m1% %m2%
echo +--+ +--+
echo   %WL%
```

so do I need to change the shape of card or what?

Comment: `if "%n1%" == "IJ I" set WL=win`

Comment: Best practice is too always use quotes when doing string comparisons. I would not suggest assigning quotes to your variables in your set commands like the answer Bill Ferguson supplied below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes around the variables and values in the `IF` statements.

Like this:

```
set n1=IJ I
set m1=I HI
set n2=IJ I
set m2=I DI
if "%n1%"=="%n2%" (
    if "%n1%"=="IJ I" set WL=win
) else (
set WL=lose
)
echo +--+ +--+
echo %n1% %n2%
echo %m1% %m2%
echo +--+ +--+
echo   %WL%
```

Comment: @Sukka, you should really use best practice when `Set`ting variables too: `Set "n1=IJ I"`, `Set "m1=I HI"`, `Set "n2=IJ I"`, `Set "m2=I DI"`, `Set "WL=win"` & `Set "WL=lose"`

Answer (score 0):

The expression doesn't evaluate to anything, that's why it is saying `I` is not expected. I think those are supposed to be strings? What you currently have is two symbols `IJ` and `I` with no operator which just doesn't work. Those 4 sets at the top should possibly be wrapped in quotes, but I'm purely guessing, like the following:

```
set n1="IJ I"
set m1="I HI"
set n2="IJ I"
set m2="I DI"
if %n1%==%n2% (
    if %n1%==IJ I set WL=win
) else (
set WL=lose
)
echo +--+ +--+
echo %n1% %n2%
echo %m1% %m2%
echo +--+ +--+
echo   %WL%
```